# Problema con git push origin master : se queda parado

Tags: git, github, push

Estoy iniciandome en github y en la consola  de git he ido a ejecutar el comando `git push origin master` y se queda parado pensando. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hay muchos posts (en español y en inglés) con el mismo problema. Podrías ver si esto te ayuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic

Comment: posts recientes, quise decir

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, intentar pegar el código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.